# how to return yes if one of the values contains a yes

Tags: excel

I have a row of values that is either Yes or No.

What formula can I use so as long as one of them cells is a Yes, it returns a yes. Or another way to explain it, to prompt a No requires all cells to be a No.

Thanks

Comment: `=IF(ISNUMBER(MATCH(A1:H1,"Yes",0)),"Yes","No")`

Comment: The **MATCH** solution is more efficient than the use of COUNTIF. **MATCH** searches the range and stops when a match is found, while COUNTIF always searches the whole range. You might wonder if ISNUMBER will slow down MATCH. Not gonna happen. But you may test the speed yourself to be sure. Of course, if the matched data is the last in the range, both solutions would be +-. **=IF(ISNUMBER(MATCH("Yes",A1:H1,0)),"Yes","No")**

Comment: @VBasic2008 - thanks for fixing my Match syntax :) Didn't even catch that.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming your yes and no’s are in cells A1:A10. Update the range in the `COUNTIF` as needed.

```
=IF(COUNTIF(A1:A10,”Yes”)>0,”Yes”,”No”)
```

Comment: A1:A10 is not a row and you can omit the >0 e.g. **=IF(COUNTIF(A1:H1,"Yes"),"Yes","No")**.